# Symfony 4.x: Doctrine getManagerForClass() not returning the right Entity Manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I'm looking to be able to get the correct Entity Manager given an entity instance (or just classname).

It was pointed out that doctrine ManagerRegistry has the method getManagerForClass, which accepts a classname and should return the correct matching Entity Manager.

However, when I call it, it always returns the default.

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            connection: default
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: App
                gedmo_loggable:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity'
                    prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                    alias: GedmoLoggable # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
        lobbytrack:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            connection: lobbytrack
            mappings:
                Lobbytrack:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Lobbytrack'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Lobbytrack'
                    alias: Lobbytrack
```

I'm testing with an entity in the **lobbytrack** database, *visitor*.

```
$entityClass = 'App\Entity\Lobbytrack\Visitor';
$this->entityManager = $this->managerRegistry->getManagerForClass($entityClass);
```

If I inspect the returned entityManager, I see that it's getting the **default** entity manager, when it should be returning **lobbytrack**.

The config of the visitor entity puts it in the appropriate namespace, which as far as I can tell, is how it determines which manager matches which entity.

```
namespace App\Entity\Lobbytrack;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Visitor
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="visitor")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Lobbytrack\VisitorRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
 class Visitor
 {
```

I'm thinking there is something about my configuration that is breaking this, but I can't see what.

Comment: If you print `get_class($entity)` with a visitor entity, what does it return?

Comment: With the way you are configuring the default bundle, it will map all the entities including the ones under App\Entity\Lobbytrack.  Move your entity to something like App\Entity2 or whatever.  You could also try switching the order in which the entity managers appear in your config file.  But even if that works, Lobbytrack will end up being in both managers.

Comment: @LioraHaydont "App\Entity\Lobbytrack\Visitor"

Comment: @Cerad, It looks like putting my default config last is working.  Still not super clear to me why, but thanks for that tip.

Comment: It is because when the default manager scans App\Entity it also picks up all sub-directories including App\Entity\Lobbytrack.  So Visitor ends up in both managers.  EM::getManagerForClass just cycles through each entity manager looking for the entity.  First one it find is return.  It is okay to have the same entity defined in multiple managers, just make sure it is what you really want.  Moving the Lobbytrack entities to another directory is probably more robust and less confusing to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the 'default' entity manager last in doctrine.yaml got this to work as expected.

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        lobbytrack:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            connection: lobbytrack
            mappings:
                Lobbytrack:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Lobbytrack'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Lobbytrack'
                    alias: Lobbytrack
        vcenter:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            connection: vcenter
            mappings:
                Vcenter:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Vcenter'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Vcenter'
                    alias: Vcenter
        default:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            connection: default
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: App
                gedmo_loggable:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity'
                    prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                    alias: GedmoLoggable # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
```